# BMW 320i 1992 Gearbox in Sports Mode

Tags: bmw, gears, tuning

My cas is a BMW e36 320i, with an automatic gear box. The gearbox has three modes, Economic, Sports and ICE. When in Economic mode, The gearbox switches smoothly between the 5 speeds, however, the switching occurs early which makes my car a little bit sluggish. When I put it in sports mode, the gear will switch at a higher RPM, which makes the car more powerfull. However my problem is that when in sports mode, the gear doesn't switch to the 5th speed. I am not sure if it is built in like this or this a problem in my car.

Also is it possible to tune the level at which the gearbox switches when in economy mode. Also to make the gear switch down when going up hill or taking out cars, I need to press the pedal almost 90% to force the gear to switch, is it possible to tune this also to make the gear switch when I press the pedal on 30-40 %.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not a BMW expert, but it would seem to me it is behaving as it should. If you want it to perform in Sport mode, why not just run it in Sport mode all of the time? If you change how the Economy mode works, it will not longer be an Economy mode, so what would be the purpose?

Comment: My problem is that when it is in sports mode, the gear is not shifting to the 5th speed

Comment: Since that is the case, you should be able to take your car to someone who can tune BMW's and get the shift points changed in the Econo mode. I doubt it is something which a layman (or someone who doesn't do this work all the time) could accomplish easily, so find a reputable tuner.